# Find number of days between two date records in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a DATE, ORDERID, CLIENTID and STOREID.

I'm trying to get the average number of days between the FIRST order date and THIRD order date for all clients who have placed at least 3 orders.

This is what I have so far but when I add OrderId, it doesn’t return anything anymore.

```
select Date, OrderId, ClientId
from ClientOrders
group by Date, OrderId, ClientId
having count(ClientId) > 3
```

Comment: Have you looked at `LEAD`/`LAG`? That query is also unlikely to return anything, unless someone (somehow) manages to make 2 orders with the same ID, on the same date (assuming `Date` is a `date`).

Comment: i havent looked at LEAD/LAG. im new to sql

Comment: I would start there then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ClientId ORDER BY Date) rn
    FROM ClientOrders
)

SELECT AVG(diff)
FROM
(
    SELECT DATEDIFF(day,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Date END),
                    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN Date END)) AS diff
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY ClientId
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3   -- at least 3 orders
) t;
```